# How is $2(\ln \tan x + c)$ simplified to $A \tan^2 x$ where $A =2c$

Tags: logarithms

I'm trying to follow this reasoning:

$1/2 \ln(4 +y^2) = \ln(\tan x) + C$

$\ln(4 +y^2) = 2\ln(\tan x) + \ln A$  ( constant 2C = A)

$4 + y^2 = A \tan^2 x$

Comment: Try seeing what happens when you use $\exp()$ on both sides.

Comment: Recall $a=b\implies $e^a=e^b$. Now apply this statement to yours and utilize properties of logarithms and exponentiation.

Comment: Between 1) and 2) where did the ln A come from?  Isn't he setting 2C = ln A, not 2C = A, as he said?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: When you take the 2 into the ln, it becomes ln (tan x)$^2$?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{2}ln(4+ y^2)= ln(tan(x))+ C$
Multiply on both sides by 2:
$ln(4+ y^2)= 2ln(tan(x))+ 2C$
Taking $A= e^{2C}$ (NOT A= 2C) we have $2C= ln(A)$ so
$ln(4+ y^2)= ln(tan^2(x))+ ln(A)= ln(Atan^2(x))$

Now take the exponential of both sides:
$e^{ln(4+ y^2)}= e^{ln(Atan^2(x))}$

$4+ y^2= Atan^2(x)$

I have used:
1)  $2ln(x)= ln(x^2)$

2)  $ln(a)+ ln(b)= ln(ab)$

3)  $e^{ln(x)}= x$

Comment: Please use \ln, \tan etc, it looks better.

Comment: So the author made a mistake?